# Want to Make my chart look responsive in D3

Tags: jquery, html, css, d3.js, responsive-design

Currently I have implemented and animated chart using D3.js which animates based on the jQuery slider. All the functionality I've implemented are working, I just want to make this chart work perfectly in the responsive mode as well. Here is the plnkr for the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/fbgrMZXwfmuuZajOotgl?p=preview

Also, please find the code for the chart below:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    div#slider {
      width: 500px;
      margin-left: 17%;
      height: 5px;
      margin-top: 4%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    svg {
      margin-left: 8%;
    }

    .x-axis {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .y-axis {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .year-bar {
      width: 130%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-top: 20px
    }

    .years {
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 68px;
      font-size: 13px
    }

    .age-bar {
      z-index: 1;
      width: 20%;
      float: left;
      left: 20%;
      margin-top: 35px;
    }

    .age {
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 4px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .xwidth {
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .ywidth {
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    path.domain {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #CCC;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="year-bar">
      <span class="years">2000</span>
      <span class="years">2010</span>
      <span class="years">2020</span>
      <span class="years">2030</span>
      <span class="years">2040</span>
      <span class="years">2050</span>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!--/*<div class="age-bar">
<span class="age">100+</span><br/>
<span class="age">80-89</span><br/>
<span class="age">60-69</span><br/>
<span class="age">40-49</span><br/>
<span class="age">20-29</span><br/>
<span class="age">0-9</span><br/>*/-->

  <script>
    $(function() {

      var extensionMethods = {

        pips: function(settings) {

          options = {

            first: "number", // "pip" , false
            last: "number", // "pip" , false
            rest: "pip" // "number" , false

          };

          $.extend(options, settings);

          // get rid of all pips that might already exist.
          this.element.addClass('ui-slider-pips').find('.ui-slider-pip').remove();

          // we need teh amount of pips to create.
          var pips = this.options.max - this.options.min;

          // for every stop in the slider, we create a pip.
          for (i = 0; i <= pips; i++) {

            // hold a span element for the pip
            var s = $('<span class="ui-slider-pip"><span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-number">' + i + '</span></span>');

            // add a class so css can handle the display
            // we'll hide numbers by default in CSS, and show them if set.
            // we'll also use CSS to hide the pip altogether.
            if (0 == i) {
              s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-first');
              if ("number" == options.first) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number');
              }
              if (false == options.first) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide');
              }
            } else if (pips == i) {
              s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-last');
              if ("number" == options.last) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number');
              }
              if (false == options.last) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide');
              }
            } else {
              if ("number" == options.rest) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number');
              }
              if (false == options.rest) {
                s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide');
              }
            }


            // if it's a horizontal slider we'll set the left offset,
            // and the top if it's vertical.
            if (this.options.orientation == "horizontal")
              s.css({
                left: '' + (100 / pips) * i + '%'
              });
            else
              s.css({
                top: '' + (100 / pips) * i + '%'
              });


            // append the span to the slider.
            this.element.append(s);

          }

        }


      };

      $.extend(true, $['ui']['slider'].prototype, extensionMethods);


      $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 100,

        create: function(event, ui) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            svg.selectAll("rect").attr("width", function(d) {
              return (d.rate * d.mid1);
            });
          }, 100);
        },
        // on slide adjust width of all rects
        slide: function(event, ui) {

          svg.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d) {


              if (ui.value >= 0 && ui.value <= 99) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid1);
              } else if (ui.value >= 100 && ui.value <= 199) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid2);
              } else if (ui.value >= 200 && ui.value <= 299) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid3);
              } else if (ui.value >= 300 && ui.value <= 399) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid4);
              } else if (ui.value >= 400 && ui.value <= 499) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid5);
              } else if (ui.value >= 500 && ui.value <= 599) {
                return (d.rate * d.mid6);
              }



              /*else{
                                     return Math.min(ui.value*d.rate, d.max);}*/
            })
        }
      });

      // create svg
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 740)
        .attr("height", 800);

      /**/

      // add 4 rects
      var data = [


        {
          row: 1,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 0,
          mid2: 0,
          mid3: 0,
          mid4: 1,
          mid5: 1,
          mid6: 2
        },


        {
          row: 2,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 4,
          mid2: 5,
          mid3: 8,
          mid4: 11,
          mid5: 17,
          mid6: 26
        },


        {
          row: 3,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 30,
          mid2: 41,
          mid3: 49,
          mid4: 63,
          mid5: 87,
          mid6: 115
        },

        {
          row: 4,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 97,
          mid2: 108,
          mid3: 125,
          mid4: 163,
          mid5: 201,
          mid6: 217
        },

        {
          row: 5,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 167,
          mid2: 182,
          mid3: 228,
          mid4: 269,
          mid5: 283,
          mid6: 309
        },

        {
          row: 6,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 234,
          mid2: 286,
          mid3: 325,
          mid4: 334,
          mid5: 356,
          mid6: 350
        },

        {
          row: 7,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 343,
          mid2: 381,
          mid3: 381,
          mid4: 398,
          mid5: 384,
          mid6: 372
        },

        {
          row: 8,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 445,
          mid2: 436,
          mid3: 444,
          mid4: 420,
          mid5: 400,
          mid6: 396
        },

        {
          row: 9,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 504,
          mid2: 503,
          mid3: 464,
          mid4: 434,
          mid5: 422,
          mid6: 400
        },

        {
          row: 10,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 577,
          mid2: 522,
          mid3: 476,
          mid4: 454,
          mid5: 423,
          mid6: 404
        },

        {
          row: 11,
          rate: 1.0,
          mid1: 599,
          mid2: 535,
          mid3: 497,
          mid4: 454,
          mid5: 426,
          mid6: 411
        },
      ];

       svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 40)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.row * 30;
        })

      .attr("height", 25)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .style("fill", "rgb(5, 106, 181)")
        .style("margin-top", 35)
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,5)");


      var ydata = [{
        "val": "0-9"
      }, {
        "val": "10-19"
      }, {
        "val": "20-29"
      }, {
        "val": "30-39"
      }, {
        "val": "40-49"
      }, {
        "val": "50-59"
      }, {
        "val": "60-69"
      }, {
        "val": "70-79"
      }, {
        "val": "80-89"
      }, {
        "val": "90-99"
      }, {
        "val": "100+"
      }];
      //add x and y axis
      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, 600]);



      var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(ydata.map(function(d) {
        return d.val;
      })).rangePoints([300, 0]);



      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(4)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d + "%";
        });

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10)
        .tickPadding(4)


      x.domain([0, 20]); 

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")

      .attr("transform", "translate(70,367)")

      .call(xAxis).append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("x", 390)
        .attr("dx", "-1.5em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("font-size", "15")
        .style("color", "grey")
        .text("Percentage of World Population");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")

      .attr("transform", "translate(70,50)")


      .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -57)
        .attr("x", -140)
        .attr("dx", "1.5em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("font-size", "15")
        .style("color", "grey")
        .text("Age Range");

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving the svg element a viewBox and setting the height/width to 100% will make it responsive e.g.

```
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 740 800");
```

Which would give you [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/LEnJfdUtpfepr0zMaLyK?p=preview)

Comment: this is giving different view on IE now, by using the viewBox. Can you please check this for IE at your end.
Thanks

Comment: Not really, IE doesn't run terribly well on my Mac.